# simple search engine using web developer 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, search

I'm working on a simple e-commerce website right now, nothing real just practicing

the problem that I'm having is how to make a simple search in the website?

i.e. if I want to search for the word "iphone" in the database of the website.

how can I do that? and how can I specify a column to search in it instead of searching the whole table?

I'm using visual web developer express 2008 and SQL server 2008

Comment: Are you wanting to search the website page text or the product catalog, which is some set of tables in the database?  These are different searches to my mind in some respects.

Answer (score 1):

I may be simplifying this but if you want to search a specified varchar column in a specified table then do this:

One. Create a new stored proc in SQL Server that takes an input param such as @IN_SearchValue
Eg.

> CREATE PROCEDURE SearchProc
>     @IN_SearchParam varchar(200)     AS
>   BEGIN     SELECT      *   FROM
>           TableName t   WHERE
>           t.ColumnName LIKE '%' + @IN_SearchParam + '%' END

Two. Reference this in .Net. One possible option is use a SQlConnection object and a SqlCommand object set-up to use the above procedure.  Plenty of examples already out there.

Three. Deliver your results to your user!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use full-text searching that is built-in in SQL server 2008. You can read more information about it on [this Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

In short, you specify what columns you want to use for your full-text search (e.g. a 'title' and a 'text' column), configure them as such in the database and then use a regular query to do a full-text search (see example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142488.aspx)).

Another option is to use a framework like [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for full-text searching, which is definately more work to setup, but gives better performance, especially if you have many many records to search.